# How to remove "0" from array and readjust the size of the array?

Tags: solidity

This function works but returns zeros when condition not met.
For instance if `limit` is 10 it will return: `2, 3, 0, 5, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0`
But instead I want it to return: 2, 3, 5, 7.
Also is there a way to do so without specifying the length of `primeswithoutzeros` ?
I can't figure out how to solve the problem...

```
function sieveOfEratosthenes(uint256 limit) constant returns (uint256[] memory primeswithoutzeros){
    uint256[] memory primes = new uint256[](limit + 1);
    primeswithoutzeros = new uint256[](limit);
    for (uint256 i = 2; i < limit; i++){
        primes[i] = i;
    }
    i = 2;
    while(i**2 <= limit){
         if (primes[i] != 0){
            for (uint256 j = 2; j < limit; j++){
                if (primes[i] * j > limit){
                    break;
                }
                else {
                   delete primes[primes[i] * j];
                }
            }
         }
        i++;
    }
    for (i = 2; i <= limit; i++){
        if (primes[i] != 0){
            primeswithoutzeros[i - 2] = primes[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the primes contiguous, then this works, but you get a bunch of zeros at the end:

```
function sieveOfEratosthenes(uint256 limit) constant returns (uint256[] memory primeswithoutzeros){
    uint256[] memory primes = new uint256[](limit + 1);
    primeswithoutzeros = new uint256[](limit);
    for (uint256 i = 2; i < limit; i++){
        primes[i] = i;
    }
    i = 2;
    while(i**2 <= limit){
        if (primes[i] != 0){
            for (uint256 j = 2; primes[i] * j <= limit; j++){
                delete primes[primes[i] * j];
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    j = 0;
    for (i = 2; i <= limit; i++){
        if (primes[i] != 0){
            primeswithoutzeros[j] = primes[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

`j` is the number of primes resulting.

If you actually want a shorter array, then you can do something like this, but it's not very beautiful. You can probably improve it.

```
function sieveOfEratosthenes(uint256 limit) constant returns (uint256[] memory primeswithoutzeros){
    require(limit >= 2);
    uint256[] memory primes = new uint256[](limit + 1);
    for (uint256 i = 2; i < limit; i++){
        primes[i] = i;
    }
    i = 2;
    uint256 k = limit - 2;
    while(i**2 <= limit){
        if (primes[i] != 0){
            for (uint256 j = 2; primes[i] * j <= limit; j++){
                if (primes[primes[i] * j] != 0) {
                    delete primes[primes[i] * j];
                    k--;
                }
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    j = 0;
    primeswithoutzeros = new uint256[](k);
    for (i = 2; i <= limit; i++){
        if (primes[i] != 0){
            primeswithoutzeros[j] = primes[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

In memory arrays cannot be dynamically sized, unfortunately.

Comment: Oh yes you're right! This works perfectly! Thank you! I see, memory arrays can't be dynamic... Do you have any suggestions on how to do to have a dynamic array? Using "storage"? But it would use a huge amount of gas I think.

Comment: Yes, don't use storage unless you want to persist the data - way too expensive. You just have to work around the lack of dynamic sizing (we old-school coders are much more comfortable with it: C doesn't have dynamic arrays, for example). In this example, it depends what you want to do with the primes. I'd probably just use my first block of code and consider `j` to be the array size.